Which episode of Jackass features Bam Margera and Brandon DiCamillo being pranked by the cops?
It happens at the start when Brandon is pretending to be a cop and tries to arrest Bam, and the real cops turn up. They are then put into the back of the police car and told they are under arrest for resisting arrest and impersonating an officer and then just as the cops start to drive they turn around and say, "and by the way I am Johnny Knoxville and welcome to Jackass".

The answer is the Bounty Hunter Intro skit in Season 3, Episode 2.

It can be seen on the MTV Vault here.

Funniest scene in all of jackass
